# Grails mail plugin send from differnet emails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a list of persons with individual emails (on different kind of mail services, for example gmail and hotmail). I want to send mail from their respective email addresses, like this:

```
mailService.sendMail {
   from "hereMail@some.com"
}
```

In order to send mail I must set the configuration in `Config.groovy`. Should I maintain all emails configuration in `Config.groovy` file? or some other solution exist for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration only allows the sending from one SMTP server. The account that sends the email is not necessarily the "from" address even though it is being emailed from that account. You should be able to use one account as the SMTP server and change the "from" as needed.

Comment: if I understood properly You suggest me to use one SMTP account configuration in config.groovy, right? 
But what if I would like to send emails from another users? For example, I have a lot of employees in my application and everyone has own address mail (only on gmail)

mailService.sendMail {
   from "hereMail@some.com"
}

Where I have to set the password for every address mail?

Comment: You don't have to specify a password for each of those from addresses. It won't actually send from their mail account, but it will instead send from the configured mail account with a different from address for the mail message instead of the from address of the configured account. Does that help clarify?

Comment: I must add persons addresses to main mail (that one configured in config.groovy) in settings in gmail account to verify address. And it works :)

Answer (score 1):

The configuration item sets the "default" from address for outgoing messages. The plugin provides a DSL that is used to specify the components of the message, including a specific From address if you want. If you don't provide a from specification in the message DSL, then it uses the configuration specified value.

Here is a snippet of code that I use in my messaging system to set a user account supplied from address on outgoing messages:

```
        mailMessage = mailService.sendMail {
            multipart true
            if (toAddresses) { to toAddresses }
            if (ccAddresses) { cc ccAddresses }
            if (bccAddresses) { bcc bccAddresses }
            from messageSpecification.from
            subject messageSpecification.subject
            if (messageSpecification.plainText) { text messageSpecification.plainText }
            if (messageSpecification.htmlText) { html messageSpecification.htmlText }
            messageSpecification.attachments.each {
                attach(it.filename, it.mediaType, it.data)
            }
        }
```

Simply replace the messageSpecification.from reference to your specific from address and you are good to go.